# Perl does not have a simple #include, OK, but WHY?

Tags: perl

Perl does not have a C style preprocessor level "include" function.  That is how it is, and there are numerous sites that explain how to more or less emulate the same sort of behavior.

The one thing I couldn't find on any of these sites is any explanation for WHY perl does not have this functionality.  Given that Perl often provides many different ways to accomplish the same thing, it is a curious omission.

Can somebody please explain why the decision was made to exclude this sort of functionality?

Comment: do is pretty similar to include in a dynamic language.

Comment: Probably because copy–pasting code like `#include` does is about the worst possible implementation of modules ever.

Comment: Perhaps, but it is a very easy and quick way to set the values on a large number of variables already defined before the #include.  For instance, for initializing parameters for a script run.  (Yes there are other ways to do that.)

Comment: Why isn't `require` adequate?

Comment: Re "Perl does not have a C style preprocessor level 'include' function." Very few languages do. It's a poor design that languages are moving away from. Modules are much better according to the tenets of Computer Science.

Answer (score 7):

Perl already has `require`, `do`, `eval` and here documents among other things. It doesn't need a builtin preprocessor, if you need one that badly, there are filters. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfilter.html

In general, nobody wants `#include`, even C and C++ programmers would mostly be happy to give it up in exchange for:

1. Faster compiles
2. Clean module system

`#include` is legacy, period. If a mainstream language designer announced tomorrow that they were adding `#include` to (your favorite language here) you'd probably see mass hysteria, laughing, and loss of confidence in that designer.

Language designers don't implement `#include` in any new language, there are simply better ways to do it. In general the trend is to attempt to achieve single pass lexing. Preprocessing requires you to incrementally expand `#includes` and potentially revisit the same characters repeatedly. It has been wrought with problems, and is one of the reasons that C++ is such dog to compile. It was ok in the 60s and 70s when memory and CPU were tiny and languages and problems were simpler, as were codebases. Nowadays, you want to be able to compile a "library" once, store its type metadata with it so the compiler can access it efficiently without rescanning it. That is what Microsoft does anyway with precompiled headers.

So what would `#include` be good for?

1. Modules ? No. See above. Modules are compiled once, export their metadata efficiently, they don't pollute the namespace of the clients, they don't recursively inject other includes, they can be distributed in binary form, among umpteen other advantages that I'm not even smart enough to think of.
2. Including macros ? No. Replace with constants, inlining and generic programming. All of which can be precompiled and expored from a module.
3. Splicing in generated code ? Better ways to do it anyway. See modules.

The only useful functionality for the preprocessor, IMO, is conditional compilation.

```
#ifdef _WIN32_
     // do windowsy stuff
#else

#endif
```

Again, Perl can do this with `do`, `eval` or `require` as well.

Comment: @ruakh - Good point. I never used `do` much, so honestly forgot about it. `eval` was well know to me. I'll revise answer, thanks.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning also that Perl used to support running scripts through an actual C preprocessor using the `-P` command-line option. This was deprecated in Perl 5.10 (2007) and removed in Perl 5.12 (2010), and never worked especially well.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense historically.  Use of #include was very common for languages circa the late '80s, when Perl started out. Perl didn't have modules until 5.0 in 1994, and that is long enough ago that it may seem like the language always had modules.  Would it be fair to say that #include is less compatible with modules than #include is with other parts of the language?

Answer (score 0):

Perl doesn't have or lack it any more than C does.

The C preprocessor was designed such that it and C need to know as little as possible about each other. There is no reason why you can't use it with Perl.

So why don't Perl programmers do it?

As codenhein explains, it's generally a bad idea to use an include mechanism with a compiler that don't know anything about each other, as it leaves you open to some crazy errors that neither can diagnose; the fact that C programmers are used to it doesn't change that.